# how to shorten modulo operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorter way to write this. It does what its meant to do. I'm just curious if you can shorten it more now with ES6.

```
var index = 0;
```

This gets update on click..

```
index = (index + 1) % 3;
```

Comment: index = ++index % 3 ?

Comment: I wouldn't want to try to shorten it anyway.

Comment: You could remove the spaces and rename `index` to `i`. But seriously, the code you have is both short and readable, not sure why you want to change it.

Comment: @Teemu It does not really matter, as in the example `index` will be overridden anyway. So nothing will change if you before that update the var to something different.

Comment: Good to know thanks all for your answers very helpful.